# Why hulu.com videos are choppy but youtube's are okay?

Tags: video, flash, wubi

I have a friend who recently installed Wubi and he mentioned that [hulu.com](http://www.hulu.com) videos are choppy (to the point of being unwatchable) whereas [youtube](http://www.youtube.com) is fine for him.  I also have the same version of Ubuntu (10.4) (although, I have a regular install, not Wubi) and I never have problems with [hulu.com](http://www.hulu.com).  I asked if he ever installed Flash and he said "No, it played out of the box without needing to do anything".

What can I do to help him?   Should I have him run Adobe's Flash installer?  I think, (but am not sure) that I did that on my machine, previously.  Does [hulu.com](http://www.hulu.com) even use Flash?  One point to mention is that he is running on a laptop, and I am running from a desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend might have better luck with the [Hulu Desktop Player](http://www.hulu.com/labs/hulu-desktop-linux).

Answer (score 0):

Fullscreen flash has terrible performance on linux. If you don't have a fast computer, it will be very choppy.

Because Flash is proprietary, there's nothing we can do except hope Adobe improves it. In the meantime, try a non-flash player whenever possible. I don't think there is one available for Hulu. The desktop player that Jorge suggested is still flash-based.

Comment: So you don't think it will help?

Comment: @SpashHit: You'll have to try it, but if it's flash that's causing the choppiness, I don't think it will help.